# How do I pull daily pytrends data for multiple keywords and save them to a .csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-trends

I've locked myself out of pytrends trying to solve this.  Found some help in an [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49732639/pytrends-google-trends-daily-freq)

There are a few elements, firstly, I don't fully understand the documentation e.g. what is the payload?  When i run it it doesn't seem to do anything. The result is I'm working with a lot of copy pasted code.

Second, I want to get keyword trend data for the year to date in a .csv

```
    import pandas as pd
from pytrends.exceptions import ResponseError
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = []
kw_list = ["maxi dresses", "black shorts"]
for kw in kw_list:
    kw_data = dailydata.get_daily_data(kw, 2020, 1, 2020, 4, geo = 'GB')
    data.append(kw_data)

data.to_csv(r"C:\Users\XXXX XXXXX\Documents\Python Files\PyTrends\trends_py.csv".)
```

I also tried:

```
df =pytrends.get_historical_interest(kw_list, year_start=2020, month_start=1, day_start=1, year_end=2020, month_end=4, geo='GB', gprop='', sleep=0)
df = df.reset_index()
df.head(20)
```

Though for my purposes `get_historical_interest` is useless because it provides hourly data with lots of 0s. The hourly data also doesn't match trends.